# How can I know the size of an user define type(class) in Java?

Tags: java, class, object, size

Is there any way to know the size of an user define type(class) in Java ?

Comment: what do you mean by size ?

Comment: for example : int type size is 32 bit.

Comment: What if it includes a reference to another object? and what if there is another object that has a reference to that object? Who are you going to clock up the size of the referred object to?

Comment: This looks like an XY-Problem. Why would you need this?

Answer (score 1):

For all the primitive datatypes you can refer to [the official java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

The size of a user defined class instance cannot be obtained accuratly using the java libraries itself (maybe a thirdparty library/program provides this feature). Although there are loats of online sources explaining how a JVM stores instance data ([this one for example](https://books.google.nl/books?id=zoAoubEN2PMC&pg=PA246&lpg=PA246&dq=java%20Object%20instance%20bytesize&source=bl&ots=EBh7aiKHv7&sig=HAvKWHE3PW8edPkKGCOMw4vNX-4&hl=nl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwisq6uhwb3WAhXBZlAKHXbwA4kQ6AEIOjAI#v=onepage&q=java%20Object%20instance%20bytesize&f=false)). Simply google for these kind of questions.